# Cannot use Exists function in anonymous list VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have is code:

```
Dim query = From usu In contexto.USUARIOS
            Where usu.DSC_USUARIO = usuario
            Select usu.ID_EMPRESA, usu.PASSWORD, usu.ID_USUARIO
Dim resultado = query.AsEnumerable.ToList
```

Then, when I try to see if something EXISTS it fails:

```
If Not resultado.Exists(Function(x) x.ID_EMPRESA = CDec(empresa)) Then
     Return "Not exists"
Else
     ...
```

I can't find how to make it work with the anonymous list "resultado"

Comment: How does it fail?  Compile error?  Exception?  Incorrect result?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```
Dim list = (From usu In contexto.USUARIOS
            Where usu.DSC_USUARIO = usuario
            Select New With 
                       {
                           .EMPRESA = usu.ID_EMPRESA, 
                           .PASSWORD = usu.PASSWORD,  
                           .USUARIO = usu.ID_USUARIO
                       }).ToList()
```

And then

```
If Not resultado.Exists(Function(x) x.EMPRESA = CDec(empresa)) Then
    Return "Not exists"
Else
    ...
```

I have not tested but should work